# focus a div on link button click

Tags: asp.net

In my page, I have a `gridview` with `link buttons` in a column.
By clicking the `link button` should show a `div` below the `gridview`.
I gave `href` in `onClientClick` event of the `link button` as follows.

```
function showDiv() {
        location.href = '#div1';
    }
```

When I click the `link button` the `div` is showing, but after the page load the page goes up.

**aspx code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridDate" runat="server" CssClass="gridview_Order" 
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#09182F" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#ffffff" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Sl No." ItemStyle-CssClass="paddng">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="25%" HeaderText="DATE" ItemStyle-CssClass="paddng">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDate" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("tblName") %>' Text='<%# Eval("dtvar") %>' OnClientClick="showDiv()" OnCommand="lbtnDate_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>  
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="25%" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-CssClass="paddng">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download Excel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("tblName") %>' OnCommand="lbtnDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>         
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br /><hr /><br />
 <div id="div1">
   <asp:GridView ID="gridOrderByUser" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" 
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#09182F" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#ffffff" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="False" >
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="2%" HeaderText="Sl No.">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblSlNo1" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>' style="color:#000;"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="cod" HeaderText="CODE" InsertVisible="False"  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="cod" ItemStyle-Width="16%"  />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IMAGE" ItemStyle-Width="18%">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="54px" ImageUrl='<%#"~/images/"+Eval("Image") %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>                    
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

So what should I do for staying the page in the `div` position.
Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by "page goes up"? if their is full postback this obvious!  plz show markup too!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the server side event of the link button you could do this:

```
OnClientClick="location.href = '#div1'; return false;"
```